# Why does this code not display my posts in a straight line?

Tags: html, performance, layout, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

```
.grid-layout .hentry {
position: relative!important;
display: inline-block;
width: 30%;
margin: 5px;
}
```

Can someone help me with this code? I placed this additional code for 3 'Posts' that should be
displayed in a horizontal but straight; upward moving line. But the posts are not displaying in a
straight line but in a descending format. Like a staircase. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you please provide us with your html code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try several solutions:
Set the `position` to `relative`
Use `<pre>` in the HTML file
If none of these work try setting the `display` for `block`
Please tell me if it works.